# pgbouncer pool going over default_pool_size

Tags: pgbouncer

Recently, our DB server got hit by high load. When I went to investigate, there were 49 queries from the same user for the same database. I checked our pgbouncer.ini, and sure enough, default_pool_size is set to 20 (we only turned it down to 20 fairly recently, it used to be higher). There are no per-database changes, and the only per-user change is not for the user in question.
Now I am checking on pools that are larger than default_pool_size + reserve_pool_size (5), and it's happening fairly regularly. E.g. in the last five minutes, from `SHOW POOLS;`:

```
                    database                    |      user       | cl_active | cl_waiting | sv_active | sv_idle | sv_used | sv_tested | sv_login | maxwait |  pool_mode  
 redacted_db                                    | redacted        |      1047 |          2 |        37 |       0 |       0 |         0 |        1 |       0 | transaction
```

I've checked `SHOW CONFIGS` to make sure the values are set as they are in pgbouncer.ini. Have I completely misunderstood how pgbouncer works? Or is there some nuance that I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching around, it seems that this issue came up because we did a `RELOAD` in order to update `default_pool_size`. While this updated the `default_pool_size`, it did NOT affect the pool size of databases that pgbouncer already knew about (which was all of them). This info was visible by doing `SHOW DATABASES`: they all remained at 100. Restarting pgbouncer entirely fixed the issue.